# XP Pro 5.1: User accounts give ""Your current security settings put your computer at risk" warning--why? Fix?

Tags: windows-xp, user-profiles, user, security-center

I'm the admin. When I log into my recently set up user session (there are two) the Win Security Center pops up a bar that says "Your current security settings put your computer at risk, click here..." bla bla bla. Why?  On my unfettered desktop (admin), I selected "I'll choose my own firewall/antivirus" and I have Comodo and Avast! running. I thought the settings/options carried over onto the users as well, at least the IMPORTANT stuff, but evidently not! HELP!

Comment: Do these programs run for the second user, or only for your admin account?

Answer (score 1):

This warning has nothing to do with the Windows Security Center warning settings. It's an Internet Explorer warning about an Internet Explorer setting. If you set IE's default security settings for the Internet or Restricted Zones too low, IE will warn you about it:
[image]

Reset your Zone security settings to recommended levels to stop getting the warning or turn off the check that causes the warning:

To disable Internet Explorer's Information Bar warnings, do this from your Administrator account:

From the Start Menu, select Run...
In the `Run..`. dialog, enter `gpedit.msc` and click `OK`. This will launch the Group Policy Editor snap-in.
Under the `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer` tree, find the setting called `Turn Off The Security Settings Check feature` double click it and change the setting to `Enabled` and click `OK` to save the setting.
[image]

That should stop IE from pestering you about your security settings in all accounts